# willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation not being called from trigger.io module listener

Tags: ios, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation, trigger.io

Following the docs here:

https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/native_events.html#ios

That reference:

https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/native/ios/Classes/ForgeEventListener.html#//api/name/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

I've tried to implement `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` I'me setting debug break points within both the method and conditions and none are being triggered. Testing this this in iOS7 and iOS6 simulators I've seen some posts that say `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is no longer supported in newer versions of iOS. What am I missing?

```
//mymodule_EventListener.m

#import "mymodule_EventListener.h"

@implementation mymodule_EventListener

//
// Here you can implement event listeners.
// These are functions which will get called when certain native events happen.
//

+ (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInt duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInt)) {
        [[ForgeApp sharedApp] event:@"mymodule.orientation_is_landscape" withParam:nil];
    } else {
        [[ForgeApp sharedApp] event:@"mymodule.orientation_is_portriat" withParam:nil];

    }
}


@end
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `+` to `-`?  It should be an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: @AaronBrager sadly no I had that orginally and just double tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the signature to: and it started working? what?

```
+ (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
```